# Show div on image on hover jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

Look at my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xLsbE/1/)

Here is the sample js code:

```
$(".box").hover(function () {
   $(this).find('.box-hover').fadeIn(100);
   $(".box-tresc").show();
},

function () {
   $(this).find('.box-hover').fadeOut(100);
   $(".box-tresc").hide();
});
```

I want the `box-tresc` div with "xxxxx" content to show in the center of the image. I tried `margin-top:-30px;` but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*UPDATED*:

Heres a fiddle containing a possible solution(pure CSS): [link](http://jsfiddle.net/nz5LG/1/)

**CSS:**

```
.box-hover {
   background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
    position: absolute;
    width: 290px;
    height: 185px;
    margin: 5px 5px 0 5px;
    opacity: 0;
    color:transparent;
    -webkit-transition:  0.4s;
    transition:  0.4s;
    line-height:185px;
    text-align:center;
}
.box-hover:hover {
    color:white;
    opacity:1;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="box">
    <div class="box-hover">some text</div>
    <div class="box-image">
        <img src="https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/mqHWHd2jm2141eD4SWowcIss1FwGmdZm3f0DxO0HCxYyWepZn8YyIKrMyrYKBlmGYU6zjiV-UQ=s460-h340-e365" />          
    </div>
    <div class="box-text">Theme 2.0
        <br><span>Created by: <em>User</em></span>    
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Does it center the text like te OP asked?

Comment: Better, now you need to update your answer with the new code and the jsfiddle ;)

Comment: great that what im looking for. thanks for other answers too!

Answer (score 1):

This is an example without moving the text "**Theme 2.0**" when hovering.

You should use `display:absolute;` like i did here in your code. 
And than you can use `margin`. 
I used `margin:-110px 0 0 50px;` *(Change it like you want)*

```
.box-tresc {
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
    margin:-110px 0 0 50px;
    color:white;        /* only to make te text more visable */
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/xLsbE/2/)**

Answer (score 0):

You could use `position:absolute` with % positioning in order to change image freely. Simply set:

```
.box-tresc {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    top: 50%;
    width: 100%;
}


.box-image {
    margin: 5px 5px 0;
    position: relative;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The most simple solution is to just add `text-algin` and `margin-top` to your `.box-tresc` class. Problem solved.

```
.box-tresc {
    display:none;

    text-align: center;

    margin-top:-100px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your css code like below and try now

```
.box {
   width: 300px;
   min-height: 200px;
   position:relative;
   background-color: #ECECEC;
   border: 1px solid #C6C6C6;
   border-radius: 3px;
   text-align: left;
   }

  .box-tresc {
    display:none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    }
```

Hope this helps..

Answer (score 0):

Try something like tt?

```
$(".box-tresc").css({"right":"20%","display":"block"});
```

Answer (score -1):

`position relative` is your friend here.

[***SEE DEMO***](http://jsfiddle.net/xLsbE/7/)

Comment: This should be expanded upon.  Perhaps add a demo for the OP to see, also ;)

Comment: After the edit, the demo IS there.  Thanks for fixing that :)  The other part of my comment is still relevant though.  Stating that `position relative` is your friend doesn't answer the question.  That is more of a comment than an answer.

Comment: hmm. my apologies, I thought I added it. I must've fat-fingered something

Comment: "Theme 2" moves down on image hover.

Comment: This is weird, that was not the code I suggested, as you can tell by my positive :relative suggestion. and the code in the fiddle said margin-top....:( I fixed it ...I think