# Description of image on mouse-hover

Tags: html

I would like to know how to display a short 1-liner description of an image when I hover over it with my mouse, using HTML.

Can anyone please let me know the exact tag/attribute for this?

Also, it would be good if you can provide a sample code.

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, some efforts can be nice... here is an example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22965438/show-div-on-image-on-hover-jquery/22965558#22965558

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use the attribute 'title'.

For example :

```
<img src = 'images/myImage.png' alt = 'an image' title = 'This is an image'/>
```

It will display a default 'info bublle' if you staya few second on the image

Otherwise you can also use JavaScript or JQuery to do some other stuff

Here some examples : http://www.jquery4u.com/plugins/30-text-captions-overlay-image-plugins/